# CSS wildcard selector not effecting style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to style a div using CSS wild card selector. So I did `div[class^="list_"]`. But the following code does not work

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  return 'list_' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```css
div[class^="list_"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

But when I do

```
div[class^=".box2 list_"] {
    color: red;
}
```

it affects the style. My understanding is a `div` which have a class starting with `list_` will have this style.But not able to understand why I need to add `.box2` in this wild card selector

Comment: Relying on the `class` attribute to list classes in any particular order is very fragile. The `^=` operator means that you expect the `class` value to *start* with some string. The code you say works actually won't work because of that `.` before "box2" but without that it would because `.addClass()` appends the desired class attribute content to the *end* of the attribute value.

Comment: Your selector is trying to match at the beginning of the class attribute value with `^=`. Try `*=` which looks for a match anywhere in the class attribute value.

Comment: You'd really be better off adding *two* classes: one to indicate that the `<div>` has been affected, like "has_list", and one for the specific count as you have now. That way you can just write your CSS selector as `div.has_list`

Comment: That's the problem with attribute selectors, although @hungerstar's comment will fix your problem, you also get another problem of it may also match classes like `list_not-needed-to-be-style` or `a-list_1`.  I would go with pointy's comment of 2 separate classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `*=`. Which looks for a match anywhere in the class attribute value.

Your current selector, `^=`, is trying to match at the beginning of the class attribute value.

See: [Attribute Selectors - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  return 'list_' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```css
div[class*="list_"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

As others have noted in the comments, *attribute selectors* can be a slippery depending on how they're implemented. In this instance, as @Pointy has mentioned, you may want to add two classes. One for the count and one to flag that it has changed.

You could also add a `data-` attribute instead of a class. Something like `data-list-count`. Then your selector would be `[data-list-count]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `*` instead of `^`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> `[attr^=value]`
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of **attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value**
>   `[attr*=value]`
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr **whose value contains at least one occurrence of value** within the string

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  return 'list_' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```css
div[class*="list_"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`^=` selects element with *attribute* `class` that *starts with* the following string. You can use `*=` selector to select *class* that *contains*:

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  return 'list_' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```css
div[class*="list_"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

---

But I'd *never* rely on such a construct - use a new class (say `list` based on your business logic) instead and then you can use `.box2.list` instead for *specificity* (note that there's no space after the dot):

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  // your business logic determining which class to add
  return 'list';
});
```

```css
.box2.list {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```